# Export Excel File from Web API c#

Tags: c#

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
 HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

 try
 {
     StringBuilder strBuilder = GenerateExcelFormat(modelPaymentDetails);
     //byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strBuilder.ToString());

     response.Content = new StringContent(strBuilder.ToString());
     //response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(array);

     response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/ms-excel");
     response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment"); //attachment will force download
     response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "PaymentSummary.xls";
     return response;
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     return response;
 }
```

but didn't download an excel file. Where I'm going wrong?

Comment: If you apply authorised attribute on the top of the function you are not able to Export the data as attachment. But if you remove the authorised attribute you are able to download the data as attachment